# Looking for the basis of the kernel of T

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let P$_2$ denote the vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients and of degree at most 2. Define a function T : $P_2$ → $P_2$ by
>   $$ T(P(x)) = x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(p(x-1))+ x\frac{d}{dx}(p(x-1)) $$

Looking for a basis for the kernel T. I got some help and found a solution where a solution xy (x)=c and y (x) = c/x however i don't  understand how c was found and how this is a basis when it's  not a vector. It went like this, i was fine until i got to the part where x is equated for.

$$x^2 p''(x-1)+xp'(x-1)=0.$$
Define a function $y(x)=p'(x-1)$ (therefore $y$ is also a polynomial), then the above equation writes as
$$xy'(x)+y=0=(xy(x))',$$
hence 
$$xy(x)=c$$and $y(x)=c/x$ with $c\in \Bbb R$. Such a function is a polynomial only when $c=0$, so $y(x)=0$ and $p'(x-1)=0$, which leads to $p$ being a constant polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at the action of $T$ on the basis $\{1,x,x^{2}\}$:
\begin{align}
      T1 & = 0, \\
      Tx & = x^{2}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}(x-1)+x\frac{d}{dx}(x-1)=x,\\
      Tx^{2} & =x^{2}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}(x-1)^{2}+x\frac{d}{dx}(x-1)^{2}=2x^{2}+2x(x-1)=4x^{2}-2x
\end{align}
Therefore $T$ is represented with respect to this basis by the matrix
$$
       \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -2\\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{array}\right]
$$
It's easy to check that the null space of $T$ consists of the constant polynomials. So a basis of the kernel of $T$ is $\{ 1 \}$.

Comment: How did you get  $
       \left[\begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -2\\ 0 & 0 & 4\end{array}\right]
$

Is the null space of T 1 because it has 1 leading 1?

Comment: Column $x_1 $ is all zero because TP(1)=0?. But how is the Y column (0,1,0) and $ Tx^2  =x^{2}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}(x-1)^{2}+x\frac{d}{dx}(x-1)^{2}=2x^{2}+2x(x-1)=4x^{2}-2x$  wouldn't it be....  $Tx^2 =x^{4}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}(x-1)^{2}+x^2\frac{d}{dx}(x-1)^{2}=2x^{2}+2x(x-1)=4x^{2}-2x$

Comment: I mean $Tx^2 =x^{4}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}(x^2-1)+x^2\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)$

Comment: @Patrick : $4x^{2}-2x = 0\cdot 1 -2\cdot x + 4\cdot x^{2}$, which has column vector representation $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -2 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: I see and column 1 is: $ 0 = 0x^0+0x^1+0x^2$ and column 2 is: $x= 0x^0+1x^1+0x^2$ last question why is this a column and not a row? Intuitive shouldn't it be $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & y_1 & z_1  \\ x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Patrick : Matrix multiplication on the right works on column vectors. When you multiply $M$ times $\begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c\end{pmatrix}$,  the result is 'a' times the first column of $M$ plus 'b' times the second column of $M$ plus 'c' times the third column of $M$. $T(a 1 + b x + c x^{2})$ is expressed in terms of such multiplication, the resulting column expressing the components of $1,x,x^{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if $p\in \ker(T)$, you could write
$$
p(x) = ax^2 + bx+c
$$
and solve for $T(p(x)) = 0$. This will give an equation of the form
$$
4ax-2a+b = 0
$$
whence $a=b=0$ and so $p$ is a constant.

Comment: But how is a constant p be a basis?

Comment: What you can conclude is that the kernel is one dimensional - can you think of a basis vector?

Comment: vector = (1,0,0)?

Comment: What do you mean by $(1,0,0)$  as an element of $P_2$?

Comment: Basis of T also it's one dimensional at there's only 1 leading one.

Comment: @Patrick Note that $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is standard basis for $P_2$. This is why we can write any polynomial in $P_2$ in the form $ax^2+bx+c$. As Prahlad argues, polynomials in $\ker T$ are spanned by $\{1\}$.